Split on regex (more than a character, maybe variable width) and keep the separator like GNU awk
In GNU awk, there is a four argument version of split that can optionally keep all the separators from the split in a second array. This is useful if you want to reconstruct a select subset of columns from a file where the delimiter may be more complicated than just a single character.
Suppose I have the following file:
# sed makes the invisibles visible...
# ∙ is a space; \t is a literal tab; $ is line end
$ sed -E 's/\t/\\t/g; s/ /∙/g; s/$/\$/' f.txt
a\t∙∙b∙c\td∙_∙e$
a∙∙∙b∙c\td∙_∙e$
∙∙∙a∙∙∙b∙c\td∙_∙e$
a∙∙∙b_c\td∙_∙e\t$
abcd$

Here I have a field comprised of anything other than the delimiter character set, and
a delimiter of one or more characters of the set [\s_].
With gawk, you can do:
gawk '{
    printf "["
    n=split($0, flds, /[[:space:]_]+/, seps)
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++) 
           printf "[\"%s\", \"%s\"]%s", flds[i], seps[i], i<n ? ", " : "]" ORS
    }
' f.txt

Prints (where the first element is the field, the second is the match to the delimiter regexp):
[["a", "      "], ["b", " "], ["c", "   "], ["d", " _ "], ["e", ""]]
[["a", "   "], ["b", " "], ["c", "  "], ["d", " _ "], ["e", ""]]
[["", "   "], ["a", "   "], ["b", " "], ["c", " "], ["d", " _ "], ["e", ""]]
[["a", "   "], ["b", "_"], ["c", "  "], ["d", " _ "], ["e", "   "], ["", ""]]
[["abcd", ""]]

Ruby's str.split, unfortunately, does not have the same functionality. (Neither does Python's or Perl's.)
What you can do is capture the match string from the delimiter regexp:
irb(main):053> s="a   b c    d _ e"
=> "a   b c    d _ e"
irb(main):054> s.split(/([\s_]+)/)
=> ["a", "   ", "b", " ", "c", "    ", "d", " _ ", "e"]

Then use that result with .each_slice(2) and replace the nil's with '':
irb(main):055> s.split(/([\s_]+)/).each_slice(2).map{|a,b| [a,b]}
=> [["a", "   "], ["b", " "], ["c", "    "], ["d", " _ "], ["e", nil]]
irb(main):056> s.split(/([\s_]+)/).each_slice(2).map{|a,b| [a,b]}.map{|sa| sa.map{|e| e.nil? ? "" : e} }
=> [["a", "   "], ["b", " "], ["c", "    "], ["d", " _ "], ["e", ""]]

Which allows gawk's version of split to be replicated:
ruby -ne 'p $_.gsub(/\r?\n$/,"").split(/([\s_]+)/).each_slice(2).
                map{|a,b| [a,b]}.map{|sa| sa.map{|e| e.nil? ? "" : e} }' f.txt

Prints:
[["a", "\t  "], ["b", " "], ["c", "\t"], ["d", " _ "], ["e", ""]]
[["a", "   "], ["b", " "], ["c", "\t"], ["d", " _ "], ["e", ""]]
[["", "   "], ["a", "   "], ["b", " "], ["c", "\t"], ["d", " _ "], ["e", ""]]
[["a", "   "], ["b", "_"], ["c", "\t"], ["d", " _ "], ["e", "\t"]]
[["abcd", ""]]

So the same output (other than the line with trailing \t which gawk has as an empty field, delimiter combination.)
In Python, roughly the same method also works:
python3 -c '
import sys, re 
from itertools import zip_longest
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        lp=re.split(r"([\s_]+)", line.rstrip("\r\n"))
        print(list(zip_longest(*[iter(lp)]*2, fillvalue="")) )
' f.txt   

I am looking for a general algorithm to replicate the functionality of gawk's four argument split in Ruby/Python/Perl/etc. The Ruby and Python I have here works.
Most of solutions (other than for gawk) to I want to split on this delimiter and keep the delimiter? involve a unique regex more complex than simply matching the delimiter. Most seem to be either  scanning for a field, delimiter combination or use lookarounds. I am specifically trying to use a simple regexp that matches the delimiter only without lookarounds. With roughly the same regexp I would have used with GNU awk.
So stated generally:

Take a regexp matching the delimiter fields (without having to think much about the data fields) and put inside a capturing group;
Take the resulting array of [field1, delimiter1, field2, delimiter2, ...] and create array of [[field1, delimiter1], [field2, delimiter2], ...]

That method is easily used in Ruby (see above) and Python (see above) and Perl (I was too lazy to write that one...)
Is this the best way to do this?

hi, have you tried anything ? (please share) (and clarify that you want this available in Ruby/Python/Perl !)

The questions is there BETTER method to a) Use a simple regex that only has to match the delimiter (ie, not regarding each field at all) and b) keep each matched delimiter. I posted both Ruby and Python examples that are working. I am asking is there a better way.

I think condition a) is too constraining, when it is possible to build the structure you want immediately with (?!$)(.*?)([\s_]+|$) in the three languages and without an additional mapping of the results. Note that this pattern isn't so complicated and can be built dynamically with the delimiter pattern.

Note: s.scan(/[^\s_]+|[\s_]*/).each_slice(2).map{|a,b| [a,b]} #=>  [["a", "   "], ["b", " "], ["c", "    "], ["d", " _ "], ["e", ""]].

@CasimiretHippolyte: Actually that pattern is very good but would fail on Rust or Go which do not support lookarounds. And, [\s_]+ was just meant as a simple example. A delimiter is potentially  a lot more complicated yet matchable without using lookarounds. Almost ALL modern languages support a) Some form of regex split and b) capturing the delimiter that caused the split and c) some form of taking an array natatime into sub arrays. Perl (with List::MoreUtils), Python, Rust, Go, Swift, Ruby, Java, Javascript, etc all do. Nice to quickly prototype something in gawk and then reuse.

You don't want lookarounds, sorry it was the first idea that comes in my mind, but you can do the same without (^|.+?)([\s_]+|$). (except for empty lines) Or to be more clear (^|.+?)(yourpatternwhateveritis|$)

Also might be worth noting .each_slice(2).map{|a,b| [a,b]} is the same as .each_slice(2).map(&:itself) which is the same as  .each_slice(2).to_a

With splitting you always have one more field than the delimiters, which is why you have to fill in an empty string as the delimiter for the last field. A simpler way to achieve the filling would be to always append an empty string to the list returned by the split so that you can use the itertools.batched function (available since Python 3.12, or as a recipe beforehand) to produce easy pairings:
import re
from io import StringIO
from itertools import batched

file = StringIO('''a\t  b c\td _ e
a   b c\td _ e
   a   b c\td _ e
a   b_c\td _ e\t
abcd''')

for line in file:
    print(list(batched(re.split(r"([\s_]+)", line.rstrip('\r\n')) + [''], 2)))

This outputs:
[('a', '\t  '), ('b', ' '), ('c', '\t'), ('d', ' _ '), ('e', '')]
[('a', '   '), ('b', ' '), ('c', '\t'), ('d', ' _ '), ('e', '')]
[('', '   '), ('a', '   '), ('b', ' '), ('c', '\t'), ('d', ' _ '), ('e', '')]
[('a', '   '), ('b', '_'), ('c', '\t'), ('d', ' _ '), ('e', '\t'), ('', '')]
[('abcd', '')]

Demo here

I appreciate @blhsing answer and all the comments. Especially the (Duh!) observation that "With splitting you always have one more field than the delimiters, which is why you have to fill in an empty string as the delimiter for the last field."
With @engineersmnky comment this is a better Ruby:
ruby -lne 'p $_.split(/([\s_]+)/,-1).<<("").each_slice(2).to_a' f.txt
#      needed to catch last match ^

(Note the -1 argument needed to split as a flag to catch the potential last match on the end of the line with Perl and Ruby. On awk and Python, this is the default.)
With @blhsing answer, this is a better Python:
python3 -c '
import sys, re 
from itertools import batched
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        print(list(batched(re.split(r"([\s_]+)", line.rstrip("\r\n") )+[""], 2)))
' f.txt   

And I finally wrote that Perl:
perl -lnE '
BEGIN {
    use strict; use warnings;
    use DDP;                        # only for printing
    use List::Util qw(pairs);
}
    my @r;

    foreach my $pair ( pairs (split(/([\h_]+)/, $_, -1), ("")) ) {
        my @e = ($pair->key, $pair->value);
        push (@r, \@e);
    }    
    my $out=np(@r, multiline=>0);
    $out=~s/(?<=[\[\]]) (?=[\[\]])//g; $out=~s/\t/\\t/g;         # only for printing
    $out=~s/(?:(?<=[\[\]]) (?="))|(?:(?<=") (?=[\[\]]))//g;      # only for printing
    say $out;
' f.txt     

Again, the goal was to split relatively more complex [field]?[delimiter][field][delimiter][field]|[delimiter] with a simple regex that targeted the delimiter alone and keep the result. I wanted to be able to prototype something on gawk because it is so universal. Then be able to confidently use the same regex in Perl, Python, Ruby or anything else that can capture what caused the split (Rust, Swift? Go cannot.)
Given the example, all (except Python prints a list of tuples) the above print:
[["a", "\t  "], ["b", " "], ["c", "\t"], ["d", " _ "], ["e", ""]]
[["a", "   "], ["b", " "], ["c", "\t"], ["d", " _ "], ["e", ""]]
[["", "   "], ["a", "   "], ["b", " "], ["c", "\t"], ["d", " _ "], ["e", ""]]
[["a", "   "], ["b", "_"], ["c", "\t"], ["d", " _ "], ["e", "\t"], ["", ""]]
[["abcd", ""]]

The same approach can be inverted to target the fields with a regex also.

@engineersmnky:  While /[^\s_]+|[\s_]*/ does work well, my goal was using split with a regex to match either field or delimiter only. One of the major goals I had here was to replicate the behavior of split on GNU awk so I could reuse the regexp that worked with awk. BTW: I love the enum_for. I learn something from you often.

Make sense. In that case I would probably go with [*$_.split(/([\s_]+)/,-1),""].each_slice(2).to_a or $_.split(/([\s_]+)/,-1).<<("").each_slice(2).to_a because the parens make me feel icky. Or if you want to use enum_for: $_.enum_for(:split,/([\s_]+)/,-1).chain([""]).each_slice(2).to_a

@engineersmnky: There you go again! Teaching me a new Ruby idiom! Change made...
